# In customer edit page from backend in shopping cart tab why all quote display if customer hasn't any item in their cart in Magneto2?

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.3.3

If customer hasn't any item in their cart, from the backend customer `edit page -> shopping cart` all the quote display.

what is exactly this?

[image]

Comment: I am unable to find "Shopping cart" tab on customer edit. Is it coming from any custom module?

Comment: Nope. It's from Magento_Customer Module. I am using Magento 2.3.3 EE

Comment: ok, might be it's 2.3 feature. I am using 2.2.5 EE, its not there.

Comment: I think there are few issues with this functionality still, check https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26921

Comment: thanks !!! @YashPatadia